# How do I cleanly test equality of objects in Mypy without producing errors?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have the following function:

```
import pandas as pd

def eq(left: pd.Timestamp, right: pd.Timestamp) -> bool:
    return left == right
```

I get the following error when I run it through Mypy:

> error: Returning Any from function declared to return "bool"

I believe this is because Mypy doesn't know about `pd.Timestamp` so treats it as `Any`. (Using the Mypy `reveal_type` function shows that Mypy treats `left` and `right` as `Any`.)

What is the correct way to deal with this to stop Mypy complaining?

Comment: why do you have such a function? do you mean to use `operator.eq` ?

Comment: Are you using specific stubs for `pandas`? Using just `mypy` on your script will result in errors with `pandas` being skipped (and no further errors). Note that the `==` operator will call `__eq__` on the compared object, so its implementation or definition will affect what you're seeing in `mypy`.

Comment: @AnthonySottile I'm not using any `Pandas` stubs which is why I assume it treats the left and right arguments as `Any`. I suppose my question is: Given two arguments that Mypy thinks are `Any` types, how can I let Mypy know that it is valid for me to compare them for equality?

Comment: What if you make a if statement to return true or false comparing them 2? Is that too bad to you? Like: `if left == right: return True`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can cast it as a bool.

```
import pandas as pd

def eq(left: pd.Timestamp, right: pd.Timestamp) -> bool:
    return bool(left == right)
```

if mypy doesn't like that you can import `cast` from typing and use that to cast it to a bool.

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import cast

def eq(left: pd.Timestamp, right: pd.Timestamp) -> bool:
    result = bool(left == right)
    return cast(bool, result)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tested it also without using the `cast` command. The Mypy check is passed without any error with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

def eq(left: pd.Timestamp, right: pd.Timestamp) -> bool:
    return bool(left == right)
```

(Tested with Mypy 0910.)